# downloading encrypted m3u8 file time limit

Tags: decryption

I wanted download videos from an app. So I used Charles to get a page which provide video url.

https://film.izdax.cn/api/v2/tv/46/url/1

this page was encoded with extra windows backslash like this.

https://vodfilm.izdax.cn/1780d12fd30b49e7bbaa93d6294cc31a/db3971e4fc114ed58b6299291f640c3d-c3eecc89c9b65cee87cd0ea7f5364d35-fd-nbv1.m3u8?auth_key=1597371862-DJtxf334nfApOzVA-0-3c4c9a59546758c9a0d6ea3e8f16076f&end=300

I removed those extra backslahses, the link became like this:

https://vodfilm.izdax.cn/1780d12fd30b49e7bbaa93d6294cc31a/db3971e4fc114ed58b6299291f640c3d-c3eecc89c9b65cee87cd0ea7f5364d35-fd-nbv1.m3u8?auth_key=1597371862-DJtxf334nfApOzVA-0-3c4c9a59546758c9a0d6ea3e8f16076f&end=300

This is playable in VLC for 5 minutes and 4 second.

This has a time limit 300 second. I would like to download full video.
I have tried to remove 300 at the end and replace with longer time limit. Non of them worked.

I tried video.js. I couldn't make it work as well.
Is there anyway to download or play the full video?

Thanks

Comment: Link is a 403. We don't have enough info to even guess.

Comment: I added more details how I ended with this link. If still 403, can get latest link from original page as I included.